# Allow subdirectory Apache 2.4

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm struggling with the htaccess system of apache.

My apache directories are set as follow:

- `www/` (Protected via /var/www/.htaccess)
- `www/public/` (Supposed to be unprotected via /var/www/public/.htaccess)

However i still can't access the public folder without the need to log in via my AuthType Basic from my `www/.htaccess`...

**www/.htaccess:**

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Acces restreint"
AuthUserFile "/var/www/.htpasswd"
Require valid-user
```

**www/public/.htaccess:**

```
AuthType None
Require All Granted
```

I really am not an expert in Apache so I may have missed the obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just figured out that what I was doing works but using H5AI as browser it needed to access the files.
I simply added a rule in the apache2.conf to prevent him being overwritten by the main directory .htaccess and all worked fine.